Creating an .ics file in the attachment of Microsoft Graph API SendEmail call
I am trying to send Email using the Graph API.
POST /me/sendMail
POST /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/sendMail

I need to create an .ics file within the body of the call as well. Having hard time giving the context of the .ics file in the body. The body I made is as following and it is working, but when I try to add the text of ics in the content of the attachment I am getting an error. How can I add it in the body?
{
  "message": {
    "subject": "<MAIL_SUBJECT>",
    "body": {
      "contentType": "HTML",
      "content": "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC -//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv=content-type content=text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1>
<style>
body{
                font-family:Calibri,Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
                }
</style>
</head>
<body bgcolor=#ffffff text=#000000>

stuff here

</body>
</html>
"
    },
    "toRecipients": [
      {
        "emailAddress": {
          "address": "<TO_EMAILADDRESS>"
        }
      }
    ],
"attachments": [
      {
        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
        "name": "Advies Bemiddelingsovereenkomst.pdf",
       "contentType": "octet-stream",
        "contentBytes": "content should be here"
      }
    ],

                "from": {
                               "emailAddress": {
                                               "name": "mail",
                                               "address": "<test@mail.com>"
                               }
    }
  },
  "saveToSentItems": "true"
}


And the .ics content is like below (for example):
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//ical.marudot.com//iCal Event Maker
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Europe/Berlin
LAST-MODIFIED:20201011T015911Z
TZURL:http://tzurl.org/zoneinfo-outlook/Europe/Berlin
X-LIC-LOCATION:Europe/Berlin
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
TZNAME:CEST
TZOFFSETFROM:+0100
TZOFFSETTO:+0200
DTSTART:19700329T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=-1SU
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZNAME:CET
TZOFFSETFROM:+0200
TZOFFSETTO:+0100
DTSTART:19701025T030000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=10;BYDAY=-1SU
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20210716T221958Z
UID:20210716T221958Z-901688629@marudot.com
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20210717T120000
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20210717T160000
SUMMARY:Stack Overflow
DESCRIPTION:iCalendar example for Stack Overflow user Ciske\n
LOCATION:Amsterdam
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Stack Overflow
TRIGGER:-PT1H
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR

I have tried to add in directly as a text in the body but issues also start to happen due to syntax as well.
And it is important to keep in mind that I need to generate the document within the body, I want to give the content within the body.
